# Javascript error: "There is an unexpected token in while loop" when using console.log

Tags: javascript

I don't know why I am receiving an unexpected token in my while loop.

```
var num = 1
while(num <= 20){
    if(num % 4 === 0)
        console.log(num);
    }
    num++;
}
```

I expect for the while loop to run successful and output the condition.

Comment: Please add more details

Answer (score 3):

```
var num = 1;
while (num <= 20) {
    if (num % 4 === 0)
        console.log(num);

    num++;
}
```

You had an extra  closing bracket at the end : (})

Comment: A little side note : If else don't need brackets when need to do simple stuff but I'd recommend always having them. So in this case you where either missing the opening one or had one extra closing one. A good practice IMO is to always have the opening and closing brackets, this way when you need to add some code you don't need to add them.

Answer (score 3):

You need either to use a [block statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block) or not, but you have a leftover `}` at the end

```js
var num = 1;
while (num <= 20) {
    if (num % 4 === 0) console.log(num);
    num++;
}
```

or a missing `{` right after the `if (num % 4 === 0) {`.

```js
var num = 1;
while (num <= 20) {
    if (num % 4 === 0) {
        console.log(num);
    }
    num++;
}
```